# Identify manufacturer of rectangular two-pin inline plug/jack?

Tags: identification, connector

Does anybody know the manufacturer of this plug? It is used in an OrigenAE-S10 PC case to connect to the case display:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The mating jack is shown below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please measure and report its exact pitch: https://forum.digikey.com/t/pitch-of-a-connector/172. Also, post pictures of the mate (the male this female plugs into). Do it soon, because people are trying to close your  question for insufficient information.